# JavaScript. Почему данный код не складывает эти элементы массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, task

Не судите строго мой код, я новичок в js, хотел бы понять в чём была моя ошибка. Было бы классно услышать еще и объяснения. Задача: 'Составить функцию, которая будет складывать все те числа  массива, которые кратны 3 и оканчиваются на 4'. Проблема: 'Числа массива, которые кратны 3 функция без проблем складывает, а числа, оканчивающиеся на 4 - нет'. Снизу будет мой код =>

```
          let input = [14, 3, 9, 14, 5];
          function ege(int) {
               let sum = 0;
               for (let i = 0; i < int.length; i++) {
                    if (int[i] % 3 === 0) {
                         sum += int[i];
                    }
                    if ((int[i].length - 1) === 4) {
                         sum += int[i];
                    }
               }
               return sum;
          }
          console.log(ege(input));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементами массив `int` в данном случае являются **числа**. У чисел нет свойства `length`, поэтому и `int[i].length - 1` не совсем корректное выражение.

Для получение последней цифры целого числа, достаточно посмотреть остаток от деления этого числа на 10.

```
if ((int[i] % 10) === 4) {
```

Кроме того, в задаче указано, что числа должны быть кратны 3 **И** оканчиваться на 4, а в приведенном примере, число может удовлетворять всего одному из условий.

Для решения нужно объединить условия в один `if` с помощью [логического И](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

```
if ((int[i] % 3 === 0) && (int[i] % 10 === 4)) {
    sum += int[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант, если нужно придерживаться двух условий одновременно:

```
let input = [14, 3, 9, 14, 5];

function ege(int) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < int.length; i++) {
    if (int[i] % 3 === 0 && int[i] % 10 === 4) {
      sum += int[i];
      
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(ege(input));
```